# How to apply Filter on datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, ado.net

Good day.
I am a beginner in vb.net and new in stackoverflow , I am encountering a problem in `Filter` method...
Below is my code:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
Dim zCondition As String = ""

If txtrid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "receiptID='" & txtrid.Text & "',"
If txtsid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkID='" & txtsid.Text & "',"
If txtsname.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkName='" & txtsname.Text & "',"
If txtsprice.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkPrice='" & txtsprice.Text & "',"
If txtsquantity.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "quantity='" & txtsquantity.Text & "',"
If txtdate.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "dateTime='" & txtdate.Text & "',"
If txtcid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "custID='" & txtcid.Text & "',"

zCondition = zCondition.Substring(0, zCondition.Length - 1)

Dim dv As DataView
dv = New DataView(DsSales1.Tables(0), zCondition, "type Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

End Sub
```

When I execute and test the code, it's give me a error `Cannot find column type.`... 
It seems this line is having error:

```
dv = New DataView(DsSales1.Tables(0), zCondition, "type Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem and explain to me what's the problem I am having? Thank you.
And sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: So when you put BreakPoint in which line it stops?

Comment: it must be telling about your `order by` - `"type Desc"`. Do you have column "type" in your data table? And also!!! I think, you need to use `AND, OR` etc in your condition, not commas

Comment: See how to build expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done:)
And sorry for I forgot to mention that I had also change the `**,**` to `** AND **`

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim zCondition As String = ""
    If txtrid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "receiptID='" & txtrid.Text & "' AND "
    If txtsid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkID='" & txtsid.Text & "' AND "
    If txtsname.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkName='" & txtsname.Text & "' AND "
    If txtsprice.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "stkPrice='" & txtsprice.Text & "' AND "
    If txtsquantity.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "quantity='" & txtsquantity.Text & "' AND "
    If txtdate.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "dateTime='" & txtdate.Text & "' AND "
    If txtcid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition = zCondition & "custID='" & txtcid.Text & "' AND "
    zCondition = zCondition.Substring(0, zCondition.Length - 5)

    Dim dv As DataView
    dv = New DataView(DsSales1.Tables(0), zCondition, "receiptID Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is totally wrong. This is how you do it

```
Dim cond As New StringBuilder(1000)
cond.Append("1 = 1") ' now, you will never add extra 'AND', 'OR' etc. 1 is always 1
' if any text box below is missing data it will not hurt anything using this technique
' NOTE spaces in front of 'AND'
If txtrid.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND receiptID='" & txtrid.Text & "'") ' removed commas
If txtsid.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND stkID='" & txtsid.Text & "'")
If txtsname.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND stkName='" & txtsname.Text & "'")
If txtsprice.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND stkPrice='" & txtsprice.Text & "'")
If txtsquantity.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND quantity='" & txtsquantity.Text & "'")
If txtdate.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND dateTime='" & txtdate.Text & "'")
If txtcid.Text.Length > 0 Then cond.Append(" AND custID='" & txtcid.Text & "'") 


Dim dv As New DataView(DsSales1.Tables(0), cond.ToString(), "COL_NAME Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

Your error most likely caused by your `order by`. You probably don't have column "type"

Another question to you is `txtsid`, `txtsprice` - are this strings? If they are not - you need to remove single quotes in your condition.

Comment: Thanks for willing to help me :)
I had solved my problem just now.
I just change "type Desc" to "my_column_name desc" and it works perfectly.
Thanks again sir. :)

Comment: @VillagerA probably because it's not what he needed, but I'll give ya a +1 for effort ;)

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR Thank you, of course. But if you look into my comment, which I posted minutes after question, it is clearly gives an answer to the problem. And I also not sure how it "works perfectly" having commas in the filter? Although, I know how. Because so far, he/she didn't use multiple criteria. Remember that comma removal line with `substring`? This is why. Let this person to try mult criteria and we'll be back to "oh, it is not working now again"

Comment: Good, I don't see how the OP says it works now by changing just the sort, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case filter can be easier than what I am seeing here...

```
  ' Create a DataView 
    Dim dv As New DataView(DsSales1.Tables(0))

    ' Filter by an expression. 
    dv.RowFilter = zCondition
```

Also in your checks you can do: `zCondition &=` to add strings... On another note get rid of `**,**` after your condition when adding on another string, use `**AND**`

Your if's can come down to this as well...

```
    If txtrid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition &= "receiptID='" & txtrid.Text & "'"
    If txtsid.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso txtrid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition &= "AND stkID='" & txtsid.Text & "'" Else zCondition &= "stkID='" & txtsid.Text & "'"
    If txtsname.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso txtsid.Text.Length > 0 Then zCondition &= "AND stkName='" & txtsname.Text & "'" Else zCondition &= "stkName='" & txtsname.Text & "'"
```

MrCodexer

Comment: What if `txtrid.Text.Length = 0` ??

Comment: @T.S. he's wanting to filter the data right, this will work. It's clear that "type Desc" isn't in his table for the sort...

Comment: And then what happens?

Comment: What happens, it doesn't add it?

Comment: umm... Because of I couldn't understand the if's you recommended to me  , I'll slowly digest it later :)